# Boot from the CD/DVD

Tags: windows-8, bootable-media

I'm having trouble to boot from a CD/DVD in my new computer with a Windows8 installed.
I've changed the first boot device in BIOS with 'CD/DVD', but doesn't work. Every time I reboot, I don't see any option, and start the Windows authentication system. What could I do? I've tried with several CD and DVD without success.

Comment: Check for `Secure Boot` and `legacy boot` option in UEFI, depending on your bootable media.

Comment: @week - Thanks, but I've disabled it and nothing changes. I've seen that in `Boot Options -> Optical Disk Drive Priority` it doesn't seem to recognize anything. However, if I enter in Windows, I can see ans access to the DVD.

Comment: Did you enable `legacy boot`? Is that DVD efi bootable?

Comment: @week - Well, it works now. I've enabled `Launch CSM` and now I see `Launch PXE OPROM [Legacy]` and `Launch Video OPROM [Legacy]`. I figure you were referring to that. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For booting from non-EFI CD/DVD, you need to Disable `Secure Boot` and Enable `Legacy Boot` or `Launch CSM` in UEFI settings.